# SQL query - how to use case?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

Hi I got some problems with my query - problems with data filtering - don't know how to do this.

```
select lo.customer_no as station_num, lo."name" as station_name, fb.aggregation_type as data_source, fbh.balance_date as balance_day,
fbd.fuel_dis as fuel_dis, fb.sales_pos_manual as fuel_manual, p.product_name as product
from fuel_balance_data fbd
join fuel_balance fb on fb.id=fbd.fuel_balance_id 
join "location" lo on lo.id = fb.location_id 
join tank t on t.id = fb.tank_id 
join fuel_balance_header fbh on fbh.id=fuel_balance_header_id 
join product p on p.id=t.product_id
where fbh.location_id in (1031, 1035, 1026, 1024, 1008, 1009, 1006, 913, 320, 1010, 888, 417, 416, 440, 408, 486, 483, 402, 398, 
395, 393, 392, 391, 538, 386, 384, 383, 1033, 382, 377, 1030, 1034, 371, 369, 368, 365, 364, 363, 424, 464, 360, 357, 354, 353, 351, 347, 346, 1021, 343, 1002, 340, 1005, 445)
and fbd.gross_net = 'GROSS'
and cast(fbh.balance_date as date) between '2020-01-01' and  current_date - integer '1' 
order by balance_date, lo.customer_no, fb.aggregation_type desc
```

Table looks like:

```
+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
| station_num| station_name            | data_source | balance_day      | fuel_dis        | fuel_manual | product  |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | MANUAL   | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |          (NULL) | (NULL)    | VP Diesel  |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | MANUAL   | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |          (NULL) | (NULL)    | SFS Diesel |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | MANUAL   | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |          (NULL) | (NULL)    | SFS 95     |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | MANUAL   | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |          (NULL) | (NULL)    | PB VPR 100 |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | MANUAL   | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |          (NULL) | (NULL)    | PB 95 VP   |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | AUTO     | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 | 1001.8800000000 | (NULL)    | SFS 95     |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | AUTO     | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |    0.0000000000 | (NULL)    | VP Diesel  |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | AUTO     | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |  993.5300000000 | (NULL)    | SFS Diesel |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | AUTO     | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |    0.0000000000 | (NULL)    | PB VPR 100 |
| 0000XXXX | LOCATION______ - 0000XXXX | AUTO     | 2020-01-26 00:00:00 |    0.0000000000 | (NULL)    | PB 95 VP   |
+----------+---------------------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------+-----------+------------+
```

Here what i want:

1. filter my query - if sales from dis is not null i want to show only auto per day
2. filter my query - if sales from dis is null and sales from cash is not null - i want to show only manual per day
3. filter and edit table - if in both cases sales from dis and sales from cash is null i want to show only manual per day and change manual to no_data

how to use propely case statement in this situation? Because i want to query data for whole month - some days got only auto, some got only manual and some got no_data.

Comment: One FROM per SELECT. Do explicit JOINs.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, simplify: [mcve]

Comment: You should at least tell us what happens when you run your query. I suppose you are getting syntax errors? Here: `fb.aggregation_type as datatype(man/auto)`, as `datatype(man/auto)` is not a valid alias name (same as `sales from cash`). Then there is `from dis` in your select clause. Is there a column named `from` that you want to give the alias name `dis`? And what is `current_date - integer '1'` supposed to mean?

Comment: As to your filter rules: When are you talking about values in a particular row, when about some or all values for one date? Do you want to look at all "dis sale" for a day and only if all of them are not null then show 'AUTO' ? Or do you want to look at all "dis sale" for a day and only if at least one of them is not null then show 'AUTO' ? And what does show only auto per day even mea? Do you want one result row per day with the text 'MANUAL', 'AUTO' or 'NO_DATA'? Or would you show all 'AUTO'  rows for the day, when all or at least one row matches your condition? ...

Comment: ... Or do you want to decide for each row i.e. look at a row and if its "dis sale" is not null and its "datatype" is ' AUTO', you want to show this particular row? Please elaborate. (And please correct your query. I suppose `fbd.fuel_dis as sales from dis` shall be `fbd.fuel_dis as "sales from dis"`, but in your result table you call it `dis sale` instead. Fix the query and make alias names match in query and result table shown. I recommend using underscores in alias names anyway, e.g. `dis_sale` or `sales_from_dis`, as these are readable valid alias names.)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `integer '1' ` can be simplified to `1`

Comment: I don't get any syntax errors. Query works smoothly - this is how array look after I used my query. For every locations I have tanks with unique product. I got data from tanks - manualy or automatic. And this sort of data I want to filter because for tipical location I got 10 row (5 tanks - auto data, 5 tanks - manual data). If i have location where auto data works I only want to show auto data for that specific day, If I don't have auto data for specific location I want to show only manual data. When i don't have both i wanna change manual to no_data and show only no_data. Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want:

1. An `aggregation_type` / `data_source` that's evaluted from `fuel_dis` and `fuel_manual`, rather than the `aggregation_type` column.
2. A ranking of the best evaluted type per location and day and only keep the best ranked.

For The evaluation use `CASE WHEN`. For the ranking you can use use `RANK`. In your case you can also rank the types alphabetically, as you want 'AUTO' to have precedence over 'MANUAL' and 'MANUAL' over 'NO_DATA'. I'm showing both approaches.

The query:

```
select *
from
(
  select
    datasourced.*,
    -- either:
    min(real_data_source) over (partition by fbh.balance_date, lo.customer_no)
      as best_real_data_source,
    -- or:
    rank() over (partition by fbh.balance_date, lo.customer_no order by real_data_source)
      as rnk
  from
  (
    select 
      lo.customer_no as station_num,
      lo."name" as station_name,
      fbh.balance_date as balance_day,
      fbd.fuel_dis as fuel_dis,
      fb.sales_pos_manual as fuel_manual,
      p.product_name as product,
      case when fuel_dis is not null then 'AUTO'
           when fuel_manual is not null then 'MANUAL'
           else 'NO_DATA'
      end as real_data_source
    from fuel_balance_data fbd
    join fuel_balance fb on fb.id=fbd.fuel_balance_id 
    join "location" lo on lo.id = fb.location_id 
    join tank t on t.id = fb.tank_id 
    join fuel_balance_header fbh on fbh.id=fuel_balance_header_id 
    join product p on p.id=t.product_id
    where fbh.location_id in (1031, 1035, 1026, 1024, 1008, 1009, 1006, 913, 320, 1010,
                              888, 417, 416, 440, 408, 486, 483, 402, 398, 395, 393, 392,
                              391, 538, 386, 384, 383, 1033, 382, 377, 1030, 1034, 371,
                              369, 368, 365, 364, 363, 424, 464, 360, 357, 354, 353, 351,
                              347, 346, 1021, 343, 1002, 340, 1005, 445)
    and fbd.gross_net = 'GROSS'
    and fbh.balance_date >= '2020-01-01'
    and fbh.balance_date < current_date
  ) datasourced
) ranked
where 
  -- either:
  real_data_source = best_real_data_source
  -- or:
  rnk = 1
order by balance_date, customer_no;
```

(I've replaced your date clause with `>=` and `<` as is common with datetimes. This may enable the DBMS to use an index and speed up access.)

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
CASE when ISNULL([sales from dis],'')<>'' then 'only auto per day'
WHEN ISNULL([sales from dis],'')='' and ISNULL([sales from cash],'')<>'' then 'only 
manual per day'
WHEN ISNULL([sales from dis],'')='' and ISNULL([sales from cash],'')='' then 'only 
manual per day and change manual to no_data' end as [Result],* 
from
(select 
lo.customer_no as [location number],
lo."name" as [location name],
fb.aggregation_type as [datatype(man/auto)],
fbh.balance_date,
fbd.fuel_dis as [sales from dis],
fb.sales_pos_manual as [sales from cash],
p.product_name as [product type] 
from fuel_balance_data fbd 
join fuel_balance fb on fb.id=fbd.fuel_balance_id  
join "location" lo on lo.id = fb.location_id  
join tank t on t.id = fb.tank_id  
join fuel_balance_header fbh on fbh.id=fuel_balance_header_id  
join product p on p.id=t.product_id 
where fbh.location_id  = 357
and fbd.gross_net = 'GROSS' 
and fbh.balance_date  < current_date - integer '1' 
order by balance_date desc)A
```

Comment: `[sales from cash]` is invalid (standard) SQL, you need to use double quotes: `"sales from cash"`